# How to convert this Python code to c#?

Tags: c#, python

I'm fairly decent at python and just starting to learn C#.

How would i write this peice of python code in c#?

```
 d =" ".join(c.split())
```

I'm a c# beginner so nothing too technical please.

Comment: what is the value in `c` and what you are expected in `d`

Comment: something like `string d = string.Join(" ", c.Split(' '));`

Comment: there didnt need to be values assigned to the variables for this question to be answered, so down voting the question was completely unneccessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see

```
 c.split()
```

is splitting string `c` by default -  (space) - delimiter; C# equivalent is

```
 c.Split(' ');
```

Pythonic

```
 " ".join
```

is collection joining with `" "` being the delimiter; C# equivalent is

```
 string.Join(" ", collection);
```

Binding all together:

```
 d = string.Join(" ", c.Split(' '));
```

Comment: @PineappleLord: you're welcome! Do not forget do declare `d` as `String` (unlike in Python in C# you have to declare local variables explicitly: `String d;`)

Answer (score 0):

d = string.Join(null, c.Split(null)); //null is your separator where you can change it to " "

Answer (score 0):

Its almost the same:

```
// splitting by space
var d = string.Join (" ", c.Split (' '));
```